# Error:cannot get automation extension for chrome with selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

Iam getting below Exception when i run test case ,this is happening after my chrome browser got updated to 62.0 version. I have updated chrome driver to 2.33 version ,even after updating facing the same issue. Selenium version being used is 2.52

```
         org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.10 seconds
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6bedf70ff9f22c647788f9fe9c8d22210e2', time: '2013-08-17 12:46:41'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Session ID: 30ad534f9914fe71f672dd12e56a0aea
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\ab83622\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6624_25177, chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233)}, networkConnectionEnabled=false, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=62.0.3202.94, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, hasTouchScreen=false, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:783)
    at com.ctlts.bpm.console.test.selenium.SeleniumRule.before(SeleniumRule.java:98)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at com.ctlts.bpm.console.test.testtools.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says it all `WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension`

As per your `Error Stack Trace` you are using :

- **`chromedriver=2.29`**
- **`chrome=62.0`**

The Release Notes of **`chromedriver=2.29`** clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v56-58`**

The Release Notes of **`chromedriver=2.33`** clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v60-62`**

### Solution :

The solution will be either to upgrade **`chromedriver`** binary to **`v2.33`** levels or to downgrade your **`Chrome Browser`** binary to **`v56-58`**