# Chrome Automation Extension has crashed

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium in C# to automate against Google Chrome.  I am using the latest version of `Chrome (78.0.3904.70)`, `Selenium.Webdriver (3.141.0)`, and `Selenium.Chrome.Webdriver (77.0.0)`.

I use: `ChromeDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();`.  Chrome opens, but does not load correctly, like in the image below, and I am unable to use any Selenium features.  What do I need to change to use Chromedriver?

I downloaded `ChromeDriver v.78` and have referenced it with `new ChromeDriver(v78 path)`, and it has the same error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately your webdriver has to match the major version number, so use chromedriver v78: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/

Comment: I downloaded `ChromeDriver v.78` and have referenced it with `new ChromeDriver(v78 path)`, and it has the same error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your post carefully enough.  Remove the browser extension.  This is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

[image: Chrome Automation Extension has crashed]

along with this error message...

[image: Aw, Snap!]

...is observed when ChromeDriver / Chrome is unable to load the default extensions.

---

Historically, the *Automation Extension* issue with *Chrome Browser* surfaced a couple of builds earlier then *ChromeDriver v2.32* and you can find a detailed discussion in [What has changed on Chromedriver 2.32 regarding loading of the automation extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709331/what-has-changed-on-chromedriver-2-32-regarding-loading-of-the-automation-extens/48713002#48713002)

Precisely, to address this error you may have to:

- Pass either/both of the flags:

  - **`disable-extensions`** flag
  - **`--no-sandbox`** flag

as argument/s when creating your [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) session. Special test environments sometimes cause *Chrome* to crash when the **sandbox** is enabled. For detaile watch [this space](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/help/chrome-doesn-t-start) as follows:

```
var option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArgument("disable-extensions");
option.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Additionally, you need to ensure that (whichever is applicable):

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** / **non-administrator** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: `option.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");` was all I needed.  Thanks for your help!