# Chrome Automation Extension has Crashed - Using Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate some stuffs via Chrome by using `Selenium in Python`

When I execute the code, I'm getting an error like in Pop-up format

[image: Pop-up is showing]

In Chrome it's showing like below

[image]

> **Note:** I found some similar stuffs but which is in `C#` reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633630/chrome-automation-extension-has-crashed/58644064#58644064) which is not actually solved my problem!

So based on my debugging I've added some chrome options in my code

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

After ran my code I'm getting an error in IDE like

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
```

As I'm new to Automation so unable to deep dive into the error can anyone help me here to move forward in my carrier

**Additinal Information**

- IDE Used: `Spyder`
- Chrome Version: `Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
- Chrome Driver: [83.0.4103.39](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.39/)
- Selenium Version: `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59`
- Python Version: `Python 3.7.0`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi `@debanjanb` I've already tried those steps in that question [58633630](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633630/chrome-automation-extension-has-crashed) Actually which was not solved my error that is the reason I've created a separate question here!